# After deleting all rows in database, first primary key is 1005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, primary-key, delete-row

I deleted all rows in my SQL Server 2012 database table.

When I create a new row, it should start with Primary Key `1` but it starts with the value of the `deleted rows + 1`.

Can I change that or shall I turn auto-increment off?

Comment: *it should start with pkey1* No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 11):

If you `delete` the records then the auto-increment value will not be touched. It will go on from the last inserted number.

If you `truncate` your table, then the auto-increment key will start from the beginning.

### It is no good idea to manually mess with the auto-increment keys. Leave them as is.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reseed the Database table. Please use following example.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (<TableName>, reseed, 0)
```

Comment: +1 for `0` instead of `1`, `RESEED` has curious behaviour in this regard.